# Need resolution for the below hung thread issue in Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere-7

I am getting the below hung thread message when the first transaction is triggered. This hung keeps on increasing and the JVM does not respond to any transactions further. I have no other option other than restarting.

```
[xx/xx/xx x:xx:xx:xxx xxx] 00000063  W UOW=null source=com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ThreadMonitorImpl org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Application Server thread=[Deferrable Alarm : 3]
          WSVR0605W: Thread "MessageListenerThreadPool : 4" (00000098) has been active for 744872 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:303)
    at com.pantero.util.collections.MapOfMaps.get(MapOfMaps.java:100)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.caching.OptimisticCacheManager.get(OptimisticCacheManager.java:22)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.builtin.BuiltInSchema.getFromCache(BuiltInSchema.java:285)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.ModelObject.getFromCache(ModelObject.java:1340)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.types.ClassType.getProperty(ClassType.java:475)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.types.ClassType.getProperty(ClassType.java:465)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.types.ClassType.getProperty(ClassType.java:458)
    at com.pantero.metamodel.types.ClassType.getRuntimePropertiesCount(ClassType.java:808)
    at com.pantero.runtime.entity.Entity.initialize(Entity.java:156)
    at com.pantero.runtime.entity.MapEntity.initialize(MapEntity.java:66)
    at com.pantero.runtime.entity.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:146)
    at com.pantero.runtime.entity.Entity.<init>(Entity.java:137)
    at com.pantero.runtime.entity.MapEntity.<init>(MapEntity.java:46)
    at com.pantero.runtime.xml.XmlEntity.<init>(XmlEntity.java:63)
    at osstM.productOrder.fal.oss.XXXXXXX.productOrder.TimePeriod.<init>(TimePeriod.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.pantero.runtime.util.RuntimeUtils.newInstance(RuntimeUtils.java:436)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.newInstanceOf(RuntimeClassMap.java:538)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.createTarget(RuntimeClassMap.java:512)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.buildTargetAndContext(RuntimeClassMap.java:467)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.setup(RuntimeTransformation.java:600)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.subMap(RuntimeTransformation.java:432)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.setTargetValue(RuntimeTransformation.java:284)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.execute(RuntimeTransformation.java:113)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeLocal(RuntimeClassMap.java:198)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeMaps(RuntimeClassMap.java:163)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.map(RuntimeTransformation.java:574)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.subMap(RuntimeTransformation.java:476)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.setTargetValue(RuntimeTransformation.java:284)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.execute(RuntimeTransformation.java:113)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeLocal(RuntimeClassMap.java:198)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeMaps(RuntimeClassMap.java:163)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.map(RuntimeTransformation.java:574)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.subMap(RuntimeTransformation.java:476)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.setTargetValue(RuntimeTransformation.java:284)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.execute(RuntimeTransformation.java:113)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeLocal(RuntimeClassMap.java:198)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeMaps(RuntimeClassMap.java:163)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.map(RuntimeTransformation.java:574)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.subMap(RuntimeTransformation.java:476)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.setTargetValue(RuntimeTransformation.java:284)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeTransformation.execute(RuntimeTransformation.java:113)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeLocal(RuntimeClassMap.java:198)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.executeMaps(RuntimeClassMap.java:163)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.execute(RuntimeClassMap.java:129)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.RuntimeClassMap.mapAll(RuntimeClassMap.java:609)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.MappingSession.mapAll(MappingSession.java:413)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.MappingSession.doInsert(MappingSession.java:601)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.MappingSession.insert(MappingSession.java:542)
    at com.pantero.runtime.mapping.CompositeMappingSession.insert(CompositeMappingSession.java:164)
    at com.pantero.runtime.domain.DomainSession.syncWithSourceSession(DomainSession.java:78)
    at com.pantero.runtime.domain.DomainSession.syncWithSourceSession(DomainSession.java:63)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataServiceSession.syncWithSourceSession(DataServiceSession.java:250)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.syncWithSource(DataService.java:928)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.insert(DataService.java:297)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.map(DataService.java:623)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.mapSingle(DataService.java:544)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.map(DataService.java:431)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.map(DataService.java:403)
    at com.pantero.runtime.dataservice.DataService.map(DataService.java:368)
    at com.xxxxx.cCBManageOrder.CCBManageOrderImpl.createOrder(CCBManageOrderImpl.java:44)
    at com.xxxxx.cCBManageOrder.CCBManageOrder$1.execute(CCBManageOrder.java:37)
    at com.pantero.runtime.lock.LockSupervisor.executeWithReadLock(LockSupervisor.java:47)
    at com.xxxxx.cCBManageOrder.CCBManageOrder.createOrder(CCBManageOrder.java:40)
    at com.xxxxx.cCBManageOrder.CCBManageOrderSDO.createOrder(CCBManageOrderSDO.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.xxxxx.osst.mediator.utils.DXSICaller.doMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxxx.osst.mediator.mc.co.DXSIMediationImpl.createOrder(DXSIMediationImpl.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaReflectionAdapter$2.run(JavaReflectionAdapter.java:152)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaReflectionAdapter.invoke(JavaReflectionAdapter.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaImplementationHandler.invokeSync(JavaImplementationHandler.java:447)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaImplementationHandler.processMessage(JavaImplementationHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:755)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.transactionGlobalActivitySessionAny(UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.java:710)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.JoinUOWNativeHandler.processMessage(JoinUOWNativeHandler.java:180)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.SCAExportMessageHelper.processMessage(SCAExportMessageHelper.java:343)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.spi.impl.ExportSCAInvoker.invoke(ExportSCAInvoker.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.binding.classicsca.ejb.EJBDefaultBindingServiceProvider$EJBDefaultBindingServiceInvoker.invoke(EJBDefaultBindingServiceProvider.java:57)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.binding.classicsca.ejb.EJBDefaultBindingServiceProvider$EJBDefaultBindingServiceInvoker.invoke(EJBDefaultBindingServiceProvider.java:40)
    at com.ibm.ws.container.binding.ejb.BaseContainerBeanImpl.invoke(BaseContainerBeanImpl.java:54)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.container.binding.sca.remote.ServiceRemoteBean_43007.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.container.binding.sca.remote.EJSRemoteCSLMed_MC_CO_ManageCustomerOrder_14131b47.processMessage(EJSRemoteCSLMed_MC_CO_ManageCustomerOrder_14131b47.java)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.SCAImportBindingHandler.processMessageLocal(SCAImportBindingHandler.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.SCAImportBindingHandler.access$0(SCAImportBindingHandler.java:535)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.SCAImportBindingHandler$1.run(SCAImportBindingHandler.java:1043)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.SCAImportBindingHandler.processClassicMessage(SCAImportBindingHandler.java:1041)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.binding.handler.SCAImportBindingHandler.processMessage(SCAImportBindingHandler.java:308)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.transactionAnyActivitySessionAny(UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.JoinUOWNativeHandler.processMessage(JoinUOWNativeHandler.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.proxy.impl.ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.proxy.impl.ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.java:862)
    at $Proxy68.createOrder(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxx.osst.mediator.ccb.co.ManageCustomerOrderImpl.createOrder(ManageCustomerOrderImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaReflectionAdapter$2.run(JavaReflectionAdapter.java:152)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaReflectionAdapter.invoke(JavaReflectionAdapter.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaImplementationHandler.invokeSync(JavaImplementationHandler.java:447)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.java.handler.JavaImplementationHandler.processMessage(JavaImplementationHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:755)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.transactionGlobalActivitySessionAny(UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.java:710)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.JoinUOWNativeHandler.processMessage(JoinUOWNativeHandler.java:180)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.proxy.impl.ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.java:1043)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.proxy.impl.ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.java:717)
    at $Proxy67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxx.osst.mediator.core.ejb.BaseSOAPInboundBean.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxxx.osst.mediator.ccb.ejb.CCBCOInboundBean.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper$PriviledgedOnMessage.run(MDBWrapper.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.callOnMessage(MDBWrapper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.onMessage(ServerSession.java:761)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.dispatch(ServerSession.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor207.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSessionDispatcher.dispatch(ServerSessionDispatcher.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:242)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._submit(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3917)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._dispatchAsyncMessage(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:2207)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._run(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3395)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.run(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:4591)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSSessionHandle.run(JMSSessionHandle.java:1045)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.connectionConsumerOnMessage(ServerSession.java:1076)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MDB is taking too long to complete. Hung threads are reported when [WebSphere detects that a thread has been active longer than the time defined by the thread monitor threshold](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/ctrb_hangdetection.html?lang=en).

Comment: HI James,
Are you saying that there is some issue with the code which was deployed?